# Make Header Responsive, sticky and be at the center + align social media icons to right + Navbar forming 2 lines whn decreasing its Width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to achieve a **2 layer** navbar where the logo and social media icons are in one line plus the navbar below the logo filling the whole width. Another problem I would love to address is when minimizing the width, the **navbar forms 2 layers** which I would want to stick to one line until the hamburger menu appears.

I've managed to make the navbar responsive when in mobile width but the logo and social media icons are distorting the hamburger menu icon. All in all, I just want help to make the navbar responsive and have a clean look. Feel free to customize to your own liking. Thanks.

```js
$(function () {
 $('.toggle-menu').click(function(){
    $('.exo-menu').toggleClass('display');
    
 });
 
});
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 300 14px/18px calibri;
    background-image: url('../images/texture.png');
 }
  

 *,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before {
  content: '';
  display: table
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  display: block
}
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
a, a:hover, a.active, a:active, a:visited, a:focus{
    color:#fefefe;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.content{
    margin: 0px 100px 0px 100px;
}

.exo-menu{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position:relative;
    background: #23364B;
}
.exo-menu > li {    display: inline-block;}
.exo-menu > li > a{
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-right: 1px #365670 dotted;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
    transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
}
.exo-menu > li > a.active,
.exo-menu > li > a:hover,
li.drop-down ul > li > a:hover{
    background:#009FE1;
    color:#fff;
}
.exo-menu i {
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  line-height: 20px !important;
}
.exo-menu .logo-banner {
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
}
.exo-menu .logo-banner h4 h5 {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}
.exo-menu .logo-banner img {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  align: center;
  width: 8%;
}
li.drop-down,
.flyout-right,
.flyout-left{position:relative;}
li.drop-down:before {
  content: "\f103";
  color: #fff;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
li.drop-down>ul{
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 230px;

}
.drop-down-ul{display:none;}
.flyout-right>ul,
.flyout-left>ul{
  top: 0;
  min-width: 230px;
  display: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #365670;
  }

li.drop-down>ul>li>a,
.flyout-right ul>li>a ,
.flyout-left ul>li>a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #365670;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #547787;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
    transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
}
.flyout-right ul>li>a ,
.flyout-left ul>li>a {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #B8C7BC;
}


/*Flyout Mega*/
.flyout-mega-wrap {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display:none;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    min-width: 742px;

}
h4.row.mega-title {
  color:#eee;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 }
.flyout-mega ul > li > a {
  font-size: 90%;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
}
.flyout-mega ul > li > a:hover,
.flyout-mega ul > li > a:active,
.flyout-mega ul > li > a:focus{
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color: #ccc !important
}
/*mega menu*/

.mega-menu {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  display:none;
  padding-top: 0;
  min-height: 100%;

}
h4.row.mega-title {
  color: #eee;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #547787;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: #365670
  }
 .mega-menu ul li a {
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 90%;
  display: block;
}
ul.stander li a {
    padding: 3px 0px;
}

ul.description li {
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    line-height: 8px;
}

ul.description li span {
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 85%;
}
a.view-more{
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin-top:15px;
  background-color: #009FE1;
  padding: 2px 10px !important;
  line-height: 21px !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
}
a.view-more:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background:#0DADEF;
}
ul.icon-des li a i {
    color: #fff;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #009FE1;
    line-height: 35px !important;
}

ul.icon-des li {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}
/*Blog DropDown*/
.Blog{
    left:0;
    display:none;
    color:#fefefe;
    padding-top:15px;
    background:#547787;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
.Blog .blog-title{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;

}
.Blog .blog-des{
    color:#ccc;
    font-size:90%;
    margin-top:15px;
}
.Blog a.view-more{
    margin-top:0px;
}
/*Images*/
.Images{
    left:0;
   width:100%;
     display:none;
    color:#fefefe;
    padding-top:15px;
    background:#547787;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
.Images h4 {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
/*common*/
.flyout-right ul>li>a ,
.flyout-left ul>li>a,
.flyout-mega-wrap,
.mega-menu{
    background-color: #547787;
}

/*hover*/
.Blog:hover,
.Images:hover,
.mega-menu:hover,
.drop-down-ul:hover,
li.flyout-left>ul:hover,
li.flyout-right>ul:hover,
.flyout-mega-wrap:hover,
li.flyout-left a:hover +ul,
li.flyout-right a:hover +ul,
.blog-drop-down >a:hover+.Blog,
li.drop-down>a:hover +.drop-down-ul,
.images-drop-down>a:hover +.Images,
.mega-drop-down a:hover+.mega-menu,
li.flyout-mega>a:hover +.flyout-mega-wrap{
    display:block;
}
/*responsive*/
 @media (min-width:767px){
    .exo-menu > li > a{
    display:block;
    padding: 20px 22px;
 }
.mega-menu, .flyout-mega-wrap, .Images, .Blog,.flyout-right>ul,
.flyout-left>ul, li.drop-down>ul{
        position:absolute;
}
 .flyout-right>ul{
    left: 100%;
    }
    .flyout-left>ul{
    right: 100%;
}
 }
@media (max-width:767px){

    .exo-menu {
        min-height: 58px;
        background-color: #23364B;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .exo-menu > li > a{
        width:100% ;
        display:none ;
    
    }
    .exo-menu > li{
        width:100%;
    }
    .display.exo-menu > li > a{
      display:block ;
        padding: 20px 22px;
    }
    
.mega-menu, .Images, .Blog,.flyout-right>ul,
.flyout-left>ul, li.drop-down>ul{
        position:relative;
}

}
a.toggle-menu{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 27px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #23364B;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



</head>

<body class="background">
     <div class="content">
     
     
        <ul class="exo-menu">
      <div class="logo-banner">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/5-u7MUhsGkbQCY50W-PPesgO5dGW3-rU5ciXu-bLe67RA4AlBfAwUXm168wcx0X9_36mjeuaTlR0ItSR3F3Po6gnpvG43Ay98vJ5kwI-4EybmMf6cSVDTwCPJYVNcAda-_TiL9gst6y5YShx9_pwkUtlzCtcvgAJB1jt1s66N5WpTuPXX1MNmOpWmOWZnhLU784BgFzNSMcSae5-huErlHLj-zgWIPRYnCzdFP5Wsy5feYsUQTKTFWsKAVYHf8HXsjqJNsbruwkhJEb_LK9L0SF4TAjHAjz1wVn7DfSyjusTXISWP51F6pSk1UJr-5SK3HMJ1zcH9T_LWExcQaQTEWRq7vLGU72vPDKbBkFy5uSBJuBXcLNZoe3eYaoUcFLZrd7HQ1sN2Wg9HYZ89fNgpec2HwIPZo3b0WeX5C1n_6s4entU9Y8LBlS3n2MJ3UB4J7Bfc4HP4JZTJVOFWgaNRW8FS2xEZlgm8W0_AK0d8uXFGubAsdr4HybA800tRgoqNwEWnIrSBpJiPbafNq1A_CpznFX6p1Kb6uoCBlEETU-U1JzT-03rfuIZbeMxPMxADjzdmbw3QIcSwkssY7B1-ZbKWstK_j3GD1WZZ_aL6DQRWROJT-xTD3FzijI3YCXjZBSeGjUxqFBzy5pS1J9V24TKTKPi23fJhpBWqjH5uVvOERKEP35a9klfvw18DD-fvq62WLFeveLiqroPS_w2U2IFgQ=w743-h667-no?authuser=0">
        <div>
          <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
          <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
          <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
          <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-behance"></i></a>
        </div>
        
      </div>
            <li><a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li class="drop-down"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Flyout</a>
                <!--Drop Down-->
                <ul class="drop-down-ul animated fadeIn">
                <li class="flyout-right"><a href="#">Flyout Right</a><!--Flyout Right-->
                    <ul class="animated fadeIn">
                        <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Computer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                
                <li class="flyout-left"><a href="#">Flyout Left</a><!--Flyout Left-->
                    <ul class="animated fadeIn">
                        <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Computer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
                    </ul>           
                </li>
                
                <li><a href="#">No Flyout</a></li>
                 
                </ul>
                <!--//End drop down-->
            
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Mega Menu</a>
                <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu">
                    <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h4 class="row mega-title">Feature</h4>
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rUk36pd-LbM/VcLb48X4f-I/AAAAAAAAGCI/Y_UxBAgEqwA/s1600/Magento_themes.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <h4 class="row mega-title">Standers</h4>
                                <ul class="stander">
                                    <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Computer</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">laptop</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Camera</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">I pad</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="view-more btn- btn-sm" href="#">View more</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <h4 class="row mega-title">Description</h4>
                                <ul class="description">
                                    <li><a href="#">Women</a>
                                        <span>Description of Women</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Men</a>
                                            <span>Description of men Cloths</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Kids</a>
                                            <span>Description of Kids Cloths</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Others</a>
                                            <span>Description of Others Cloths</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                    <a class="view-more btn btn-sm " href="#">View more</a>
                                             
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                            <h4 class="row mega-title">Icon + Description</h4>
                                <ul class="icon-des">
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Web</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>Mobile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-h"></i>Responsive</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>Desktop</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>UI/UX</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="blog-drop-down"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> Blog</a>
                <div class="Blog animated fadeIn">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-VG_e0pKfrDo/VcLb6JwZqfI/AAAAAAAAGCk/8ZgA9kZqTQ8/s1600/images3.jpg">
                        <div class="blog-des">
                    <h4 class="blog-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod 
                            tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
                            nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate. </p>
                            <a class="view-more btn- btn-sm" href="#">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-hUt5FrdZHio/VcLb5dlwTBI/AAAAAAAAGCU/UUH5N1JkoQc/s1600/images1.jpg">
                        <div class="blog-des">
                        <h4 class="blog-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod 
                            tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
                            nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate. </p>
                                    <a class="view-more btn- btn-sm" href="#">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-A7U1uPlSq6Y/VcLb5kKHCkI/AAAAAAAAGCc/7WghyndTEuY/s1600/images2.jpg">
                        <div class="blog-des">
                        <h4 class="blog-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod 
                            tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
                            nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate. </p>
                                    <a class="view-more btn- btn-sm" href="#">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     
                    
                </div>
            </li>
            <li  class="images-drop-down"><a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-photo"></i> Images</a>
                <div class="Images animated fadeIn">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <h4>Images Title </h4>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-VG_e0pKfrDo/VcLb6JwZqfI/AAAAAAAAGCk/8ZgA9kZqTQ8/s1600/images3.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h4>Images Title </h4>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-hUt5FrdZHio/VcLb5dlwTBI/AAAAAAAAGCU/UUH5N1JkoQc/s1600/images1.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h4>Images Title </h4>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-A7U1uPlSq6Y/VcLb5kKHCkI/AAAAAAAAGCc/7WghyndTEuY/s1600/images2.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h4>Images Title </h4>
                        <img class="img-responsive"  src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-hGrnZIjzL2k/VcLb47kyQKI/AAAAAAAAGCQ/J6Q2IAHIQvQ/s1600/image4.jpg">
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
                <div class="contact">
            
                </div>
            </li>
      
            <a href="#" class="toggle-menu visible-xs-block">|||</a>        
    </ul>
     
     
     </div>
  
  <section>
    <main>
    <aside>
        <figure>
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
        </figure>
    </aside>
    <article>
        <header>
            <h2>Siargao</h2>
        </header>
        <p>Siargao is a tear-drop shaped island in the Philippine Sea situated 800 kilometers southeast of Manila in the province of Surigao del Norte.</p>
        <footer>
            <span> 19/05/2020</span>
        <a href="#">read more</a>
        </footer>
    </article>
</main>
  </section>
```